# What formula would plot a line with a 3% year to year reduction from an initial goal?

Tags: linear-algebra

#### The Requirement

I have some pretty simple logic written in ActionScript that plots points on a graph. The intent is to produce a line that demonstrates a 3% reduction year to year from the initial goal over a period of X years.

For example if the first year (0) goal was 100 the goal at year (1) would be .97 and at year (2) would be 94.09 and so on. The trick is that I need to plot this in quarters so every fourth quarter would be a 3% reduction from the previous years' goal. That is the intent.

#### The Attempt

I found a reference to what I think is the proper formula for doing this on a year to year basis. Using R to plot a few points I believe that the formula should be: $$f(n) = GOAL * .97^n$$ where N is the number of years since the initial goal.

The logic I wrote in the application predates this discovery and strongly suspect the calculations are wrong as a result. To address the quarters I subtracted 3% divided by 4 from 1 to get my quarterly coefficient of 0.9925. $$0.9925 =100 - .03 / 4$$

Within the application I looped over each quarter and multiplied the previous goal by 0.9925 to get the new goal and plotted it. This I now know to be incorrect.

#### The Questions

I have a couple of questions related to this.

1. How would I derive the proper formula from the requirements given above. I would like to understand how to derive this rather than stumbling upon the correct answer.
2. How would I modify f(n) to work by quarters and maintain the 3% reduction each year?
3. What formula would describe what the admittedly incorrect logic is doing?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $f(n)=\text{GOAL}\times a^n$, where $n$ is the number of quarters.  You want $f(4)=\text{GOAL}\times 0.97$, which simplifies to $a^4=0.97$.  Take a fourth root to find that $a\approx 0.992414$, indicating that you want approximately a $0.7586\%$ reduction each quarter, not $0.75\%$.

What is incorrect about the logic is that percentages can't be divided (or multiplied) like that.  The $3\%$ reduction you want over a period of one year is taken relative to the amount at the beginning of the year, whereas the smaller reductions occurring each quarter are taken relative to the amounts at the beginning of each quarter.  Because those amounts go down throughout the year, the percentages have to go up to compensate.

To take an extreme example, you can't reduce by $100\%$ by making two reductions of $50\%$.  That is, $0.5^2=0.25$, giving only a $75\%$ reduction.

Related: [Apply a 1% discount 100 times - elegant way to solve?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/294771/apply-a-1-discount-100-times-elegant-way-to-solve)